# Setting up Django and Webpack on dev server using api subdirectory

Tags: django, webpack, django-urls, webpack-dev-server

**Context:**

I'm using Django as a backend and Vue/Vuetify as a separate frontend.  I use Apache to serve the frontend and Django is strictly for api calls in a client/server setup.

I've set up WSGIScriptAlias to serve from [base_url]/api  instead of the site root. I deployed the project and it's serving django request/repsonses from /api as expected.

In my dev environment, I am running 2 concurrent dev servers.  I'm running the webpack dev server (port 10000) for the frontend project, and the django runserver on a separate port (10001) to service my requests when developing.

in webpack I've set up the following:

```
devServer:{
        hot: true,
        port: 10000
        historyApiFallback: true,    
        host: 'localhost',
        //django api
        proxy:{
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:10001',
                pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''},
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea here is that any time I request something from http://localhost:10000/api then it will redirect automatically to localhost:10001, which mimics how the production instance works since production cuts off the /api portion of the request.

**Problem:**

When I run the dev webpack and django server, I can successfully request localhost:10000/api and get a django response, but I noticed that when I attempt to access http://localhost:10000/api/admin, which should bring up the django admin page, Django redirects to http://localhost:10000/admin.

I'm looking for a way outside of WSGIScriptAlias (since I can't use that in my dev instance unless I set up a local apache / virtualhost which I've experienced has refresh issues when django is modified).

Is there a way I could do one of the following?

A) in production not have WSGIScriptAlias / Django in production drop the /api portion of the request (which would make url patterns consistent across all environments)

B) possibly set up a Base URL in Django Settings or runserver to include /api so that it doesn't try to redirect without the /api

C) perhaps something in webpack that I'm missing for the devserver setup?

**Full Disclosure:**
There is another question that asks something *similar* ([How to set base URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420478/how-to-set-base-url-in-django)) but is different because it looks like they are talking about production, i'm talking about a dev instance.  Their solution was also to use WSGIScriptAlias which I can't use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most ideal solution, but adding /api to the end of WSGIScriptAlias seems to have standardized everything between dev and production.  In order to keep from having to add 'api/' to the front of all my base url patterns I created a wrapper around Django.urls.path and Django.urls.re_path which utilizes a base_pattern variable within the module:

**/etc/apache2/sites_available/app.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ...
   WSGIScriptAlias /api /path/to/django/wsgi.py/api
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**utils/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path


base_pattern = ''

def base_path(broute,bview,bkwargs=None, bname=None):
    global base_pattern
    return path(route=base_pattern + broute, view=bview, kwargs=bkwargs, name=bname)

def re_base_path(broute,bview,bkwargs=None,bname=None):
    global base_pattern
    return re_path(route=base_pattern + broute, view=bview, kwargs=bkwargs, name=bname)
```

now I just import my utils.urls module and use that when i'm looking for a base pattern to be included.  It's not a perfect solution but gets the job done.

**Cite:**
https://serverfault.com/questions/555955/can-i-configure-apache-mod-wsgi-so-that-the-alias-url-path-is-not-stripped-befor