# Deploy Django in subdomains

Tags: django, apache, url, dns

I want to deploy a django app into an existing webenvironment, with other sites already existing.

Therefore i received a domain from the webadmin like this: `www.websites.com/theapp`

Now, in my local development environment the path `/theapp` does not exist, because the project is starting on `/` and the project folder is called `/myapp`

Myapp's urls.py is pointing to two included apps like `/app1` and `/app2`

I tried to add `/theapp` to the urls, what really doesn't work.

As i am fairly new to Django i would appreciate any assistance on how to handle this leading path, so Django could handle the incoming url correctly.

Comment: "I tried to add /theapp to the urls", show us what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420478/how-to-set-base-url-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should configure Web Server (like nginx, apache, etc...). Below is the Nginx configuration:

```
location /theapp {
  ... something uwsgi configuration or proxy_pass things ...
}
```

After that, set up Django's `urls.py` file to accept requests starting with the path `/theapp`.

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('theapp/', include('yourapp.urls')),
]
```