# How to set base URL in Django 3.2.5

Tags: django

I would like to run Django from location https://www.example.com/abc/ so that I have the admin interface at https://www.example.com/abc/admin/. And web app login interface at https://www.example.com/abc/

Where can I set the base URL of Django to https://www.example.com/abc/?

Django Version=3.2.5

Tried
path('abc/', views.getLogin, name="Login Page"),
path('abc/login', views.handeLogin, name="handleLogin"),

But these are not working, while b below admin path is working fine.

path('abc/admin/', admin.site.urls),

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate to [How to set base URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420478/how-to-set-base-url-in-django)

Overall is django a highly used and well documented project. Most common questions are answered multiple times.

EDIT:
If you want to change f.e. the whole admin path use urlpatterns in the urls.py of your base project.

```
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    path('abc/admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```