# How to configure BaseURL in Django4?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to `django` and trying to set a `baseURL` in `django4`. I came upon [How to set base URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420478/how-to-set-base-url-in-django) of which the solution is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^someuri/', include([
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls) ),
        url(r'^other/$', views.other)
    ])),
]
```

but this import statement:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

shows:

```
Cannot find reference 'url' in '__init__.py'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That... import statement is not in the solution at all?

Comment: @AKX sorry, typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.conf.urls` has been replaced by `django.urls` ([actually back in Django 2.0, in 2017](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax)), and `url` is `re_path` these days.  However, if you don't need a regexp route, just use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#path):

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "someuri/",
        include(
            [
                path("admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
                path("other/", views.other),
            ]
        ),
    ),
]
```